# Commission Update Formulas

Tags: formula, process-builder

I am writing a formula for commission updates in process builder. This is the criteria

Field is estimate writer user

- user (name of user 1) receives $50,
- user (name of user 2) receives $45,
- user (name of user 3) receives $35,
- default to $35 if the above arent true

Here is my formula

```
IF(
    [Case].Estimate_Writer_18_char_Id__c = "0055C000003rxQLQAY", /*Brian Wilson*/
    [Case].Difference_between_Settled_Original__c   * 0.50,
    IF(
        [Case].Estimate_Writer_18_char_Id__c = "005G00000083PkDIAU", /*Jeremy Wolfe*/
        [Case].Difference_between_Settled_Original__c   * 0.35,
        IF(
            [Case].Estimate_Writer_18_char_Id__c = "0055C000003rxQBQAY", /*Sarah McGarvey*/
            [Case].Estimate_Writer_18_char_Id__c = "0055C000003rxQzQAI", /*Lisa Pickett*/
            [Case].Difference_between_Settled_Original__c   * 0.45,
            [Case].Difference_between_Settled_Original__c   * 0.35
        )
    )
)
```

I think I am way off, can someone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to explain what you mean by "way off" -- are you getting errors?  Are the results incorrect?  What is your specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Looke to me like what you have is close (your last `IF()` has too many parameters), but instead of working to fix it, let me suggest some better approaches.

Instead of chaining `IF()` together, you could use `CASE()`. It'd be less typing, easier to read, and hopefully harder to make a mistake with.

```
Case( [Case].Estimate_Writer_18_char_Id__c,
    /* each pair of parameters after the first is the test string */
    /* followed by the value to return if there is a match */
    "0055C000003rxQLQAY", 0.5,
    ...
    /* final parameter is the default value */
    0.35
) * [Case].Difference_between_Settled_Original__c
```

It's also unclear if this needs to be done through Process Builder (which you should consider using a Flow instead of PB), or if it could simply be a formula field on `Case`.

Using Process Builder/Flow with a Field Update action generally means you'll go through update triggers an extra time, whereas a formula field does not cause that to happen (and is recalculated on every page view or query).

Comment: derek this need to be accomplished through a process builder. Sorry for not making it clear

Comment: @AlexvanderMerwe You should have a very good reason to be going with Process Builder at this point. If you don't know why that's a requirement, you should find out why.  Flows are what Salesforce is currently going to continue development/support for. Again though, if a formula field wwould satisfy your requirements, it'd be better to use that instead. The progression is usually 1) Try to do it with a field. 2) Try to do it with a Flow. 3) Try to do it with a trigger.

Comment: this is what was given to me Currently commission is tracked using a formula field. I think we need to change this to automation because I don't want the legacy value changing if we update the formula